# SDL_Image IMG_Load fails on png with: "Failed loading libpng16-16.dll:"

Tags: windows, load, png, sdl-2, sdl-image

Whenever I try to load a PNG using SDL_Image's IMG_Load function it gives the error `Failed loading libpng16-16.dll:`. I have all the right dll's in the right path and I can use other parts of SDL_Image, but for some reason it can't load the libpng dll. How can I fix this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What IDE are you using? Is it Visual Studio by any chance? If so, are you debugging directly from VS, or running the compiled executable directly?

Comment: I am using visual studio and I am debugging within VS. would running it another way make a difference?

Comment: Directly running the compiled executable makes no difference. Same result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See my article "[SDL2: Loading Images with SDL_image](http://www.programmersranch.blogspot.com/2013/11/sdl2-loading-images-with-sdlimage.html)":

> If you're going to run from Visual Studio, make sure the image is in the same folder as your main.cpp file; otherwise if you're running straight from the executable, the image should be in the same folder with it.

Needless to say, what I wrote about the image here goes for the DLLs as well.

Comment: I have placed the DLL along with the images in both the directory of the executable and the directory of the source. Still get the same error. Are there any additional libraries needed to use libpng?

Comment: In the project for that blog post I have libjpeg-9.dll, libpng16-16.dll, libtiff-5.dll, libwebp-4.dll and zlib1.dll along with the obvious SDL2.dll and SDL2_image.dll. If you're only including libpng, I suggest you try including all the rest - there may be a dependency that you and I are not aware of. In fact I just checked, and libpng requires zlib: http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html

Comment: That was the issue. I copied libjpeg-9.dll, zlib1.dll, and libtiff-5.dll into the needed directories and now it works with no error. Thank you.

Answer (score 25):

It appears that `libpng16-16.dll` has a dependency on `zlib1.dll` for MinGW-w64 (32-bit). Try to include zlib into your dependnecies--include the DLL in the folder where the executable runs.

Comment: I should also mention that `zlib` is one of the most popular libraries in the world and PNG uses the compression from `zlib` as a part of its format.

Answer (score 1):

The VS do not searches dlls on anywhere except the execution dir, so you probably need to copy that dll to the Debug/ directory on your solution's path.

Comment: I already have that along with the other necessary libraries in the Debug directory.

Answer (score 1):

Very niche answer, but for those running into this issue because of pySDL2, it could be caused because your python interpreter is sub-par. For me, using the windows store install for python interpreter 3.10, gave this issue. However, when I switched to 3.10 from python.org all my issues were fixed.

Answer (score 0):

[This link](http://zamma.co.uk/setup-sdl2-in-visual-studio/) show you how to set up SDL library/libpng16-16.dll to be available for acceess by the compiler.exe (the last step right before the sample code)

yourProgram proprety page -> Builds event-> post-build event 
in my case i have
copy “C:\Users\MehdiB\Desktop\C Program\Library\SDL2-devel-2.0.4-VC\SDL2-2.0.4\lib\x86\SDL2.dll” “$(OutDir)SDL2.dll”;
copy “C:\Users\MehdiB\Desktop\C Program\Library\SDL2_image-devel-2.0.1-VC\SDL2_image-2.0.1\lib\x86\SDL2_image.dll” “$(OutDir)SDL2_image.dll”;
copy “C:\Users\MehdiB\Desktop\C Program\Library\dll\libjpeg-9.dll” “$(OutDir)libjpeg-9.dll”

[here](https://github.com/OctaForge/OF-Windows/find/master) where you can get this dll

Answer (score -2):

i just replaced zlib1.dll in system32 and SysWOW64 with the one downloaded from 
https://github.com/OctaForge/OF-Windows/blob/master/bin_win32/zlib1.dll
.and worked nicely

Comment: Replacing dll files in system32 and SysWOW64 is a very bad practice, you might break Windows!
You'd better put this dll in the same directory as the binary, it's much safer.