# Failing to load a png image in SDL2

Tags: c++, dll, linker, sdl-2, sdl-image

I am trying to load PNG image, but it always ends in an error. I was first trying to use SDL's `SDL_LoadBMP`, but since that dind't work, I downloaded `SDL2_image.h`, did all the setup, but it still isn't working. The image is in the same directory as the cpp file. When I run my program, it runs, but prints error. Here is the function to load the image:

```
void loadImage()
{
    image = IMG_Load("Untitled.png");
    if (image == NULL)
        std::cout << "error: " << SDL_GetError();
}
```

The error message from `SDL_GetError` is `Failed loading libpng16-16.dll: The specified module could not be found.` I tried passing the full path, but it gives an error and I don't know how to get around that problem since I am a beginner. Thanks.

Edit: After reading through the article linked in the answer to the tagged-duplicate question and making some changes(particularly installing the missing dll file and putting it in the same directory as the main cpp flie), I am getting this error message in a pop-up window: `The procedure entry point inflateValidate could not be located in the dynamic link library`, and the path to `libpng16-16.dll` is given after that.

Comment: That DLL needs to be in one of the available environment `PATH`s when you run the program. Is it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SDL\_Image IMG\_Load fails on png with: "Failed loading libpng16-16.dll:"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21472958/sdl-image-img-load-fails-on-png-with-failed-loading-libpng16-16-dll)

Comment: Re-read the error message, it's explicitly giving you the name of the dll it's failing to find.

Comment: I just finished reading through the article linked in the answer to the tagged-duplicate question. Followed the steps, did everything it said, but now I am getting this error message in a pop-up screen: `The procedure entry point inflateValidate could not be located in the dynamic link library`

Comment: in what library? `zlib` presumably? then sounds like you have an older or newer DLL that lacks said function, right?