# Failed Error : Failed loading libpng16.dll: The specified module could not be found. when using sld2-image with c++

Tags: c++, dll, sdl, sdl-2, vcpkg

I am trying to use `sdl2-image`, but I get the following error:

```
Failed Error: Failed loading libpng16.dll: The specified module could not be found.
```

Using:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "SDL2/SDL_image.h"

int main(int argc, char* args[]) {
    if (!(IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_PNG))) std::cout << "Failed Error : " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I am using Visual Studio compiler with ninja build system and `vcpkg` in `clion`.

There should be no error when using `IMG_Init` but I keep geting the error.

Comment: dll is present in the vcpkg folder but the project is not able to find it.

Comment: You may also need the zlib dll. [SDL_Image IMG_Load fails on png with: "Failed loading libpng16-16.dll:"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21472958/sdl-image-img-load-fails-on-png-with-failed-loading-libpng16-16-dll)

Comment: zlib dll is also present in the vcpkg folder but I still get the error I also tried the solution from here SDL_Image IMG_Load fails on png with: "Failed loading libpng16-16.dll:" – 
Retired Ninja. but no success.

Comment: @Rohit and do windows know anything about this "vcpkg folder"? If it isn't in the PATH, it wouldn't look there when searching for dlls. "Usual" approach is to put dlls in either the same directory your executable is located in, or into system directory.

Comment: @keltar yes, the vcpkg folder is in the PATH and also I tried to put dlls in cmake-build-debug folder where the executable is located.

Comment: @Rohit make sure your executable and dlls are targeting the same CPU architecture . Try loading your dll into dependency walker (the same dll that you're loading - which is in your executable' directory) to check if all dependencies are met.